# Android | how to use com.android.setupwizardlib

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-library

How I can use [com.android.setupwizardlib](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/setupwizard/+/09546ca/library/src/com/android/setupwizardlib) in my project? 
This library isn't on jcenter or as gradle dependency.
This library is used in some apps (Such as Greenify) and it uses the XML tag com.android.setupwizardlib.SetupWizardLayout in my Activity
Any solutions about it?
I know how to import a library, I only need help with this specific google library
[Greenify SetupWizardLib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUD8A.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler for you to use existing packaged libraries for this functionality, such as [some of these](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/131) or [a couple of these](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/198).

Otherwise, grab [the source code and resources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/setupwizard/+/09546ca/library), add them to your project (directly or via a separate library module), and make changes as needed to get it to build.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed my problem wth your help :D